# I need to Check the preloaded checkbox from one API based on the Value of Another API, How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
      HTML;
    
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <title>Document</title>
                          
                </head>
                <body>
                    <table id="Table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>List</th>
    <th>Push Notification&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox'  name='all_push' id='all_push' class='all_push' /></th>
    <th>SMS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' name='all_sms' id='all_sms' class='all_sms' /></th>
    <th>Call&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' name='all_call' id='all_call' class='all_call' /></th>
    <th>Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='checkbox' name='all_email' id='all_email' class='all_email' /></th>
    </tr>            
    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    JS;
            
    Here I have to do two things, first I have to fetch the checkboxes which I have access, from one API . Then I have to check the checkboxes based of another API value .
            
    Here I fetched the check boxes from the API,
            
    function getlist(t, e) {
                    
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: base_api_url,
    dataType: "json",
                        success: function (t) {         
                            
                            t.length > 0 ? $.each(t, function (t, a) {
                                    var push_notif_checked = push_notif_disabled = '';
                                    var sms_checked = sms_disabled = '';
                                    var call_checked = call_disabled = '';
                                    var email_checked = email_disabled = '';
                                    if(a.push_notification == 'No') {
                                        push_notif_disabled = 'disabled';
                                    }
                                    if(a.sms == 'No') {
                                        sms_disabled = 'disabled';
                                    }
                                    if(a.call == 'No') {
                                        call_disabled = 'disabled';
                                    }
                                    if(a.email == 'No') {
                                        email_disabled = 'disabled';
                                    }
                                    
          e += "<tr class='extra_rows'><td>" Mobile "</td><td><input type='checkbox'id='push_notification' class='push_notification'/></td><td><input type='checkbox'  class='sms' /></td><td><input type='checkbox'  class='call' /></td><td><input type='checkbox'  class='email' /></td></tr>"
                                }) :e="<tr class='extra_rows'><td colspan='2'>No data found.</td></tr>",
                                $("#Table1").append(e)
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            toastr.error("Something went wrong ")
                        }
                    })
                };
```

Now I have to make another Ajax to check the Checkboxes based on Json Result,

For Example Consider my JSON result format as follows,

{
"Phone_list":"no need",
"Push_notif":"Yes",
"Sms_notif":"No",
"Call_notif":"Yes",
"Email_notif":"No"
},

I need to Check the Checkboxes of Push notification if the JSON value of Push_notif is "Yes", Likewise how can I do it for SMS,Call,Email based on JSON result shown in above row by row,I have stuck in this for a while, can somebody help me ?

Comment: Please format your question so it is readable. At a minimum mark the things that are code (and *only*) those things as code.

Answer (score 0):

For checking the checkbox you could use the following jQuery examples.

`.checkboxClass` this is the example class name of the checkbox.

Use this to check the checkbox:

```
$('.checkboxClass').prop('checked', true);
```

And for unchecking the checkbox:

```
$('.checkboxClass').prop('checked', false);
```